# PLSQL - How to retrieve the maximum value except if another specific value exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking to join data between two tables and want to retrieve the maximum semester except if a specific value also exists from a table where a person can have multiple semesters. Our semester system is coded as 'YEAR-numerical month value' ex: 12 = December. My test script looks for students from August 2021 and I want to see what their maximum semester is except if the value is '2022-8'. I want that number to be prioritized and pulled in, even if there is a higher value like '2023-1'.

This is the simplified script where it's currently just looking at the maximum semester. I've tried IF and OR statements but keep getting generic errors so I don't know what i'm doing. Thank you for any help.

```
SELECT a.person
       i.field_of_study
       i.semester
FROM application_data a
 LEFT JOIN information_table i ON i.person = a.person
WHERE a.semester = '2022-8'
 AND i.semester = (SELECT max i2.semester
                   FROM information_table i2
                   WHERE i2.person = a.person
                    AND i.semester <= i2.semester)
```

The data table might look like this:

```
|    Person A         |      Biology     |     2022-5       |                           
|    Person A         |      Biology     |     2023-1       |                        
|    Person B         |      Chemistry   |     2022-1       |                        
|    Person B         |      Psychology  |     2022-8       |                         
|    Person C         |      Mathematics |     2022-8       |                          
|    Person C         |      Statistics  |     2023-1       |
```

I would want the output to look like this:

```
|    Person A         |      Biology     |     2023-1       |                           
|    Person B         |      Psychology  |     2022-8       |                           
|    Person C         |      Mathematics |     2022-8       |
```

Person A it chose the highest max semester as the prioritized semester does not exist. Person C it chose the prioritized semester even though there was a higher max value.

Comment: "except if the value is 2022-8" - what happens if value **is** 2022-8? Could you post some sample data that illustrate the problem and result you want to get?

Comment: Just added some examples.

Comment: Can you share some data from the second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to *rank* rows per person by semester in descending order, where 2022-8 ranks as *the highest* even though there are other "higher" values; finally extract rows whose rank = 1.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (person, field, semester) as
  2    (select 'A', 'biology'    , '2022-5' from dual union all
  3     select 'A', 'biology'    , '2023-1'  from dual union all
  4     select 'B', 'chemistry'  , '2022-1'  from dual union all
  5     select 'B', 'psychology' , '2022-8'  from dual union all
  6     select 'C', 'mathematics', '2022-8'  from dual union all
  7     select 'C', 'statistics' , '2023-1'  from dual
  8    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
  9  temp as
 10    (select person, field, semester,
 11       row_number() Over
 12       (partition by person
 13        order by case when semester = '2022-8' then 1E9
 14                      else to_number(regexp_substr(semester, '^\d+') ||
 15                                     lpad(regexp_substr(semester, '\d+$'), 2, '0'))
 16                 end desc) rn
 17     from test
 18    )
 19  select person, field, semester
 20  from temp
 21  where rn = 1;

PERSON     FIELD       SEMESTER
---------- ----------- ----------
A          biology     2023-1
B          psychology  2022-8
C          mathematics 2022-8

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you. I believe this is something that I could work with.